# Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

HELP. i use react hook, i got the error when i type the input.

error:

> Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Code:

```
const AddUser = () => {
const initialUserState = {
    id: null,
    name: '',
    age: 0
}

const [users, setUsers] = useState(initialUserState)

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setUsers({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })

    e.preventDefault()
}    

return (
    <div>
        <input name="name" type="text" value={users.name} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input name="age" type="number" value={users.age} onChange={handleChange}/>
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: Your handle change is only setting the name or age, so the other becomes undefined.  If you just want to change one property in an object try using the spread syntax.  Alternatively use a separate state for age and name.

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike setting the state in a class component, `useState` doesn't merge the object you pass, and you have to do it manually when setting the state. When you set `age`, for example, you replace the entire state object, which makes `name` to be `undefined`, and vice versa.

Use [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), and create a new state based on the previous state object before setting it.

```js
const { useState } = React

const AddUser = () => {
  const initialUserState = {
      id: null,
      name: '',
      age: 0
  }

  const [users, setUsers] = useState(initialUserState)

  const handleChange = (e) => {
      // create the new state and set it
      setUsers(prev => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }))

      e.preventDefault()
  }    

  return (
      <div>
          <input name="name" type="text" value={users.name} onChange={handleChange}/>
          <input name="age" type="number" value={users.age} onChange={handleChange}/>
      </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <AddUser />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

[This page](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) and [this paragraph](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) can help you understand the problem.

When you get the updated input through the `onChange` event listener you don't need to pass again the data through the `value` attribute.

When data is passed through the `value` attribute the component is considered "controlled". This means that the component is controlled by your code and shouldn't receive user input.

If you just want to set a default value you can use the `defaultValue` attribute.

To remove the warning just remove the `value={/* Something */}`.

Comment: This is probably the most overlooked solution. When the state object tries to set a value which is controlled by the form component, then this issue emerges. This answer is valid in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i figured out changing input atribute name from:

```
<div>
     <input name="name" type="text" value={users.name} onChange={handleChange}/>
     <input name="age" type="number" value={users.age} onChange={handleChange}/>
</div>
```

to:

```
    <div>
         <input name="fullname" type="text" value={users.fullname} onChange={handleChange}/>
         <input name="age" type="number" value={users.age} onChange={handleChange}/>
    </div>
```

for example in this i change name for fullname, due to react does not recognize it as a constant but as the attribute of the input